# 'shared/error_messages' partial not rendering when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why my 'shared/error_messages' partial isn't being rendered when it should be (i.e. when an invalid 'treating' is submitted through this form):

_treating_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@treating) do |f| %>  
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :requestee_id %></div>  
    <div>
        <%= f.text_field :proposed_location, placeholder: "Propose a location here..." %>
    </div>    
    <div>
        <%= f.text_field :proposed_date, placeholder: "Propose a date here..." %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :intro, placeholder: "Write your introduction here..." %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This _treating_form.html.erb partial is called in a users/show.html.erb view:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <% if signed_in? %>
            <section>
                    <%= render 'shared/treating_form' unless current_user?(@user) %>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Here is my error_messages partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
        </div>
        <ul>
            <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li>* <%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The error_messages partial is correctly being rendered upon validation errors triggered in submitting to user 'edit settings' page:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why the errors aren't being shown when an invalid 'treating' is being submitted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add ANY options to a partial you need to explicitly specify :partial =>

```
= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
```

Comment: the error messages page is called '_error_messages.html.erb'. i thought the underscore prefix made that a partial by definition, but perhaps i'm mistaken because the call to 'shared/error_messages' in the edit settings page (last code block above) works just fine, but doesn't require mentioning 'partial' as you state

Comment: it does make it a partial by definition. However, when using render to call a partial, rails lets you ommit =render :partial => and write simple =render only when you are calling withOUT options. Since you are calling with option object: f.object, you must write out partial: as well.

Comment: ok, i see. however this is working just fine for the "Edit user" page:  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %> [despite the fact that i am passing it that object: f.object option, and omitting :partial]